# WebStorm find usage of Meteor registered Helper

Tags: meteor, webstorm

I am using WebStorm 11 and have this Meteor code in a file.js

```
Template.registerHelper('session', function( value ) {
  return Session.get(value);
});
```

Is there a way to find where in the project this helper has been used? Thanks

Comment: "Find usages" for 'session' literal should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for "session" in whole project (or in a particular folder)
by Edit > Find > Find in Path

Answer (score 0):

You can just search for `{{session` in your `client` folder.